# How to define "current" in artificial neural network?

Tags: theoretical-neuroscience

How do neuroscientists define current/current densities in artificial neural networks?

Assume I have some deep network and I would like to study its dynamic/evolution in time during the training session what kind of model are there to study the flow?

Maybe there is some information I can extract from the PDE's of back-propagation? or some evolution of the Graph $G=(V,E)$ in time.

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16269/4397

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**
In artificial neural networks currents are not involved, other than those flowing *in silico* in your pc. Instead, those currents are represented by weighted mathematical functions.

**Background**
Artificial neural networks as applied in machine learning (*e.g.*, [deep learning](https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-is-deep-learning/)) perform stuff like automatic feature extraction from raw data, also called feature learning. These models are algorithms that have little to do with the basic physiology of neurons. Hence, current/current density is not a matter of interest. It's the coupling between elements that matters, namely which cells couple to which cells and how strong that interaction is (Fig. 1).

> A given node [(Fig. 1)] takes the weighted sum of its inputs, and
>   passes it through a non-linear activation function. This is the output
>   of the node, which then becomes the input of another node in the next
>   layer. The signal flows from left to right, and the final output is
>   calculated by performing this procedure for all the nodes. Training
>   this deep neural network means learning the weights associated with
>   all the edges.

<sup>source: [Towards Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-1-artificial-neural-networks-d7834f67a4f6)</sup>

In other words, there is no current involved, only weighted functions.

[image: ANN]
<sup>Artificial neural network. source: [Towards Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-1-artificial-neural-networks-d7834f67a4f6)</sup>

Comment: So what's the mathematical/physics formalism to study the interactions?

Comment: @0x90 I think you need to do a bunch of your own research here before asking such broad questions. Especially because it sounds like you want to approach this with a research interest.

Comment: @BryanKrause I have something in mind, but I couldn't find the standard approach while googling stuff. That's why I think it's a legit question.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'the standard approach' here, and the content of your original question also suggests you have a bit to learn first.